# How to get just a message's preamble and epilogue using IMAP

Tags: email, imap, mime, rfc822

MIME messages can have so-called *preambles* and *epilogues* (see RFC 2046), which are ‘discardable’ text parts outside of the MIME harness (boundaries).
One application is to signal that the message is a multi-part MIME message to non-MIME capable clients.

IMAP servers allow partial fetches of all kinds of parts and subparts of a (MIME) message, but I did not find a way to get *just* the preamble and epilogue. (Of course it is possible to fetch the whole message and do client-side MIME parsing, but I would like to use the server.)

Is it possible to fetch just the preamble and epilogue, or not? If yes, how?

(This is just out of curiosity, without a specific application in mind.)

Comment: You know, I don't think you can; at least I can't find any part specifiers that would help.

Answer (score 1):

There's no really good way, but you could hack it with `x UID FETCH BODY.PEEK[TEXT]<0.1023>` to get the preamble and a little more. A similar command with some arithemetic should give you the epilogue, again assuming it's no longer than 1024 bytes.